# HANA Cloud Data Source issue with Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, jndi, jpa-2.1, sap-cloud-platform

I need to deploy the Spring based Java Application in the HANA Cloud, i am not able to get the Data source giving error

```
2016 05 17 14:33:45#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-11#14:33:45.128 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR c.s.c.r.k.p.client.PersistenceDataSourceFactory - An exception occurred during rest communication with local config service: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:20002/config/v1/services/persistence/jdbc/someothername|
2016 05 17 14:33:45#INFO#LJS_OUTPUT#Thread-11#14:33:45.129 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR c.s.c.r.k.p.client.PersistenceDataSourceFactory - Retrieved persistence properties are null!|
```

Here is the Data source config details

[image: Datasource binding]
and my web.xml as below

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/someothername</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

and the i tried though JNDI Lookup

```
@Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
  final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/someothername");
        return dataSource;
  }
```

and i tired directly as

```
@Resource
DataSource dataSource
```

and also

```
@Resource("jdbc/someothername")
DataSource dataSource
```

Help me how to solve this issue

Thanks
Chiranjeevi GK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that your database ID is named *tutorial* and that you use a HANA trial instance, I assume that you only need one data source / schema anyway.

In the [HANA Cloud Platform documentation](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm) you can find two different approaches of how to get a database connection with tomcat 7 (Java Web SDK):

1. [Adding Application-Managed Persistence With JPA](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e4aeacd2bb5710148ee99255136d96a5.html)
2. [Adding Persistence With JDBC](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/help/frameset.htm?e4c52854bb571014aeb88753d0dad158.html)

The best way would be to have a look at these tutorials and to choose the way you prefer. The tutorials provide a lot of details.

My guess is, that the issue is caused because you gave your data source a custom name ("*someothername*"). If you only use one data source, you should always call it *DefaultDB*:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/DefaultDB</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
</resource-ref>
```

Then your JDBC lookup looks like this:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB");
```

The data source in HANA Cloud Cockpit would then be called `<default>` (including the angled brackets). To do that, just delete your current data source binding and add a new one.

[image: Data Source Binding Example]

Comment: Yes i am using trail verson, i have to give the data as "jdbc/DefaultDB"